# To skip the strings from a file and append floating numbers in list

Tags: string, list, floating-point

if I have a floating numbers and I want to convert it into list but it also contain strings, how to skip strings and pass all the floating numbers in list

Comment: Please provide some sample input and output. You didn't mention the programing language as well.

Comment: list = ['NaN','37','45','46','a','32']

list2 = []
try:
    for item in list:
        if item == 'NaN':
            list.remove(item)
            continue
        elif item == 'a':
            list.remove(item)
            continue

    list = [float(item) for item in list]
    print(list)


except ValueError:
    print("Skipping line number 18 : could not convert string to float: 'a'")

Comment: How about the `a` in the list ?

Comment: I want to skip the strings using try and except. For example, if a string is 'a', then using try and except I have to show that print("Skipping line number 18 : could not convert string to float: 'a'") and if it's a NaN, I want to skip that string. I tried a lot of things but unable to do it

Comment: Posted on answer session.

Answer (score 0):

If you only fetch the numbers in the list

```
lst = ['NaN','37','45','46','a','32']
lst = [i for i in lst if i.isdigit()]
```

Result:

```
 ['37', '45', '46', '32']
```

if you want to convert the above list into a float number

```
lst = list(map(float, last))
```

Result:

```
[37.0, 45.0, 46.0, 32.0]
```

And if you want to remove item using  `try-except` you can do like this,

```
In [1]: for item in lst[:]:
   ...:     try:
   ...:         float(item)
   ...:     except TypeError:
   ...:         lst.remove(item)
   ...: 

In [2]: lst
Out[2]: ['37', '45', '46', '32']
```